# How to render a simple triangle with glMultiDrawArraysIndirect?

Tags: opengl, opengl-4

I decided to pick up OpenGL and now that I've rendered a simple triangle I want to learn how to use other ways to render like `glMultiDrawArraysIndirect`

There doesn't seem to be any simple examples online that contain this function. I tried searching GitHub for open source code but it's mostly documentation and complex frameworks.

Can somebody explain the steps to render a Hello World Triangle with `glMultiDrawArraysIndirect`?

Here's the following working code I used to render a simple triangle. I have a 4.5 OpenGL enabled card.

```
static const char * vs_source[] =
{
    "#version 450 core                                                 \n"
    "                                                                  \n"
    "void main(void)                                                   \n"
    "{                                                                 \n"
    "    const vec4 vertices[] = vec4[](vec4( 0.25, -0.25, 0.5, 1.0),  \n"
    "                                   vec4(-0.25, -0.25, 0.5, 1.0),  \n"
    "                                   vec4( 0.25,  0.25, 0.5, 1.0)); \n"
    "                                                                  \n"
    "    gl_Position = vertices[gl_VertexID];                          \n"
    "}                                                                 \n"
};

static const char * fs_source[] =
{
    "#version 450 core                                                 \n"
    "                                                                  \n"
    "out vec4 color;                                                   \n"
    "                                                                  \n"
    "void main(void)                                                   \n"
    "{                                                                 \n"
    "    color = vec4(0.0, 0.8, 1.0, 1.0);                             \n"
    "}                                                                 \n"
};

program = glCreateProgram();
GLuint fs = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
glShaderSource(fs, 1, fs_source, NULL);
glCompileShader(fs);

GLuint vs = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
glShaderSource(vs, 1, vs_source, NULL);
glCompileShader(vs);

glAttachShader(program, vs);
glAttachShader(program, fs);
glLinkProgram(program);

glCreateVertexArrays(1, &vao);


while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
{
    const GLfloat green[] = { 0.0f, 0.25f, 0.0f, 1.0f };
    glClearBufferfv(GL_COLOR, 0, green);

    glUseProgram(program);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);

    glfwSwapBuffers(window);
    glfwPollEvents();
}
```

Comment: What part of the function do you have a problem with?

Comment: @NicolBolas Just replacing `glDrawArray` isn't enough it seems (blank output). I'm not exactly sure how to use the function since I can't seem to find any simple examples online. That's why I'm seeking for an explanation/example on how the function works to produce an output.

Comment: Presumably, you've [read the documentation](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/glMultiDrawArraysIndirect.xhtml), right? My question is what part of that is unclear to you. Do you know how the regular `glMultiDrawArrays` works? Or is your problem the proper buffer object setup work?

Comment: @NicolBolas I read but I'm not sure how to set up the buffers since it doesn't talk about that in the docs. Is it the same as `glMultiDrawArrays`? I haven't looked into `glMultiDrawArrays` yet. If so then it sounds like the right direction!

Comment: @Tek man,you can find complete examples on how to do it on g-truck.net or download the source code of OpenGL 4.3 orange book.Also from your code it is impossible to see how you are trying to do that.Your draw call is also wrong.

Comment: @MichaelIV Which part? Also g-truck.net doesn't seem to exist.

Comment: @Tek http://www.g-truc.net/project-0026.html